# How can I programmatically select a VectorFeature in GWT-OpenLayers?

Tags: java, gwt-openlayers

The javascript version provides [OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature.select](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature.select), but the Java/GWT version does not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how to do selections [in this example](http://demo.gwt-openlayers.org/gwt_ol_showcase/GwtOpenLayersShowcase.html?example=Select%20and%20edit%20feature%20example)

Click on the "View source" button to get the source code.

To make the selection programmatically you can do:

```
SelectFeature programmaticallySelectFeature = new SelectFeature(layer);
programmaticallySelectFeature.select(feature);
```

Comment: Would you elaborate on the answer please?